# batch script to log out from gmail account

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to windows batch programming. I want to write a batch script which on execution opens a browser and log outs from the gmail account if its logged in. Is there a way to log out from a gmail account using windows batch programming?

Comment: Does it have to be batch? Can you use power shell?

Answer (score 0):

with the LogOut link :

```
start firefox.exe http://mail.google.com/mail/?logout^&hl=en
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line to sign out of a Google account:

```
start chrome.exe https://accounts.google.com/Logout?hl=en
```